# Custom content in CRM 2011 Ribbon

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I need to show some custom content in the Ribbon bar that is not a button.

My question is if it's possible to show something that is not a button, and show instead some values that I need to set on load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is not supported out of the box feature neither possible with [CRM 2011 Visual Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/).

But you can still make it with unsupported ribbon changes on XML and Onload javascript function. [How to Edit ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327952.aspx).